# How can I deploy a Next.js app using Caddy and a subpath?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, next.js, caddy, caddyfile

I'm currently doing an app with Next.js `8.0.3`.

Everything is fine in local. However I have some troubles when I deploy the app using Caddy.

About my Next.js part I'm using a Custom server and to serve this server I'm doing this:

```
next build
NODE_ENV=production node server.js
```

The problem itself is about routing the app to a subpath like `/beta` to run all the app inside this subpath.

**Caddyfile**

```
localhost:8000

proxy /beta http://localhost:3000/
```

When I run the app opening `http://localhost:8000/beta` in the browser, the HTML is loaded correctly but aren't loaded all the styles, assets and javascript files. Neither the navigation between pages. It's looking these files behind `/`, and I was expecting behind `/beta`.

[image: devtools]

Copying the url that is failing and trying to find the correct path adding `/beta`, the files aren't there neither...

[image: file]

Nevertheless, without the subpath `/beta` (if I use directly the root `/`) everything is working fine. But is not the solution that I'm looking for because I have more apps running behind the same domain.

There is a workaround that solve this is this particular example. Is to proxy also `/_next` and `/static`. But is not a good solution for me, for different reasons:

1. Is not possible to run more than 1 Next.js app like `/beta`, `/alpha`.
2. This solution don't fix the navigation between pages.
3. I want to fix this (if is possible) in the Next.js part, not in Caddy part doing a workaround.

Looks that is something regarding about the Next.js part. But I'm quite lost about it. I tried to change the `assetPrefix: '/beta'`, and then is looking for the files on `/beta/file` instead of `/file`. But the files aren't there neither...

Can somebody help me?